# Access data to set method by constructors

Tags: java, class, constructor

I'm using Java and my code is BUILD SUCCESSFUL, but I don't get result I want. I'm tring to pass data input from user in main class to another class called Staff. I guess during runtime my data never pass through set and get methods to checked. How can I make them work?

Main class

```
     System.out.print("please enter staff ID: ");
     String staffID = in.next();
     System.out.println("please enter staff first name and last name:");
     String Fname = in.next();
     String Lname = in.next();

     Staff staff= new Staff (staffID, Fname, Lname);
                                
     System.out.print(staff.toString());
```

Staff Class

```
public class Staff {
     private String StaffID; 
     private String Fname;
     private String Lname;
     
     Staff (String StaffID, String Fname, String Lname){
              this.StaffID = StaffID;
              this.Fname =  Fname;
              this.Lname =  Lname;
     }
     
     //set & get Staff ID
     public void setStaffID (String StaffID){
         if (this.StaffID.length() <= 7)  { 
              this.StaffID = StaffID;
              }
              else
              System.out.println("ID have to be less than or equal 7 digits");
     } 
     
     public String getStaffID (){
              return this.StaffID;
     }
     
     //set & get First name
     public void setFname(String Fname){
              if (Fname.matches("[a-zA-Z]")){
                       this.Fname =Fname;
              }
             else
                  System.out.print("Name have to contains letters only");
     }
     
     public String getFname(){       
              return this.Fname;
     }

     //set & get Last name
     public void setLname(String Lname){
              if (Fname.matches("[a-zA-Z]")){  
                       this.Lname =Lname;
              }
               else
                  System.out.print("Name have to contains letters only");
     }
     
     public String getLname(){       
              return this.Lname;
     }     
     
              @Override
     public String toString(){
         return "\n\t\tStaff information \nID:  " + this.StaffID + "\nFirst name: " + this.Fname
                 +"\nLast name: " +this.Lname ;      
     }
```

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://ideone.com/ybXYDu). --- The getters are not used in the code presented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your constructor to use the setters like

```
Staff (String StaffID, String Fname, String Lname){
   setStaffID(StaffID);
   setFname(Fname);
   setLname(Lname);
}
```

Comment: @Haneen Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post) --- [Questions seeking debugging help (*"why isn't this code working?"*) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).